# excel delete duplicate values from rows

Tags: duplicates, rows

I need to remove the duplicate values from each row for many rows.
For example:

```
597 2733    2710    2710    2687    2687    2687    2687
597 2710    2688    2688    2687    2687    2687    2687
597 2688    2713    2713    2734    2734    2734    2734
```

I need only

```
597 2733    2710    2687
597 2710    2688    2687    
597 2688    2713    2734
```

Any suggestions how can it be done?

Comment: each number is placed into a separate cell within a row?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes they are in seperate cells

Answer (score 1):

Need to modificate this code / then you can delete / just now only mark

```html
Sub DuplicateValuesFromRow()
'Declare All Variables.
Dim myCell As Range
Dim myRow As Integer
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
'Count Number of Rows and Columns
myRow = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Count
myCol = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count
'Loop Each Row To Check Duplicate Values and Highlight cells.
For i = 2 To myRow
Set myRange = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, myCol))
For Each myCell In myRange
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myRange, myCell.Value) > 1 Then
myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the data into one column and go to Data tab in excel , you will find button called remove Duplicate

hope it helps